# Can $\mathbb{C}$ be totally ordered?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, order-theory, well-orders

If $|\mathbb{C}|=|\mathbb{R}|$ and thus $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, why can't $\mathbb{C}$ be totally ordered?

Comment: there *is* a lexicographic order for $\mathbb C$, but it's not compatible with  multiplication; cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492897)

Comment: It can be (assuming AC). But there's no way to do it in a way that is compatible with the field operations. For instance. Is $i$ positive, or negative? Either way you'll reach a contradiction by multiplying by $i$ repeatedly

Comment: @HallaSurvivor:  you don't need AC if you don't insist on a well order.

Comment: Note that the word "isomorphic" requires context.  It means there is a bijection preserving some structure, but what structure?  They are isomorphic as sets, but not as fields.  There exist bijections between them, but those bijections cannot be field isomorphisms; they cannot preserve the algebraic structure.

Comment: @NateEldredge They are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$. :)

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{C}$ can indeed be totally ordered as a set, since you can find a set bijection to the reals. But for a field the definition of a total order requires that all squares be positive. Since $1$ is positive and $-1$ is negative the fact that $i^2 = -1$ implies that no total order exists.