# Why can't we use this technique to compare complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have heard that you can't compare complex numbers... Well it is true because it's not defined on the real number line, you can't compare imaginary quantities... But I just wanted to know that why can't we compare them using their modulus?

For example, let's say we have two complex numbers:

$$z_1 = 4 + 3i \quad \text{ and } \quad z_2 = 7 + 9i$$

Now we take their modulus,

$$|z_1| = 16 + 9 = 25 \\
|z_2| = 49 + 81 = 130$$

Now we could say that $z_2$ is greater than the first one right?

Comment: There are orders on $\mathbb C$, but they are not compatible with multiplication; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492890/ordering-on-complex-numbers)

Comment: Right, $\mathbb C$ cannot be made an ordered field. Your order is called a “pre-order,” because $|a|\leq |b|$ and $|b|\leq |a|$ does not imply $a=b.$

Comment: You totally can compare their moduli, as you've demonstrated. But this comparison only claims that one has a bigger modulus, not that one is bigger than the other. If both number have the same modulus and one has a bigger principal argument, then which is the "bigger" number?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers

Comment: An "*order*" on $\,\mathbb C\,$ where all non-zero numbers are greater than $\,0\,$ is neither consistent with the usual order on $\,\mathbb R\,$ nor too useful. For example, $\,1\,$ and $\,-1\,$ would both be greater than $\,0\,$.