# complete ordered set with least upper bound property

Tags: complex-numbers, order-theory, complete-spaces

Is there any order that can make complex numbers complete ordered set with least upper bound property?

I came up with $x+yi > m+ni$ if $x+y>m+n$ and if sum is equal then the complex number with greater real part is greater.

will this work? if not, are there any examples?

Comment: See [Total ordering on complex numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers) for a negative answer and, if that doesn't answer your question, then please define what you mean by a `complete ordered set`.

Comment: no. It doesnt answer. I mean ordered set, with no field axioms defined on them.

Comment: If you mean a totally ordered set, just define a+bi<c+di  if  and only if  a<c or (a=c and b<d), the lexicographical order.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, of course. Since the set $\mathbb C$ of all complex numbers has the same cardinality as the closed interval $[0,1],$ you can define an order on the complex numbers which makes $(\mathbb C,\lt)$ order-isomorphic to $([0,1],\lt).$ This is of no interest, because the ordering you get has nothing to do with the algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal does not work.  For instance, the set $\{a-ai:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is bounded above but has no least upper bound.  Its upper bounds are all numbers $x+iy$ with $x+y>0$, and there is no least such number (since, for instance, there is no least value that $x+y$ can take).

For a simple correct example, just pick any bijection $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$, and define an ordering $\preceq$ on $\mathbb{C}$ by $a\preceq b$ iff $f(a)\leq f(b)$, where $\leq$ is the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$.  Since the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, so is $\preceq$.