# Difficult system of equations with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I'm attempting to code an AC power circuit simulator (for fun, imagine that) and I'm running into a mathematical stump. **I've simplified the problem into these equations:
$$a=bx+c$$
$$d=ex+f$$
$$P=|a||d|\cos(\theta_a-\theta_d)=a_R d_R+a_I d_I(=a\cdot d)$$
Where $a, b, c, d, e, f,$ and $x$ are all complex numbers, $P$ is a real number, and we know the values of $|a|, b, c, e, f,$ and $P$.**

I know you can't really do a dot product between complex numbers but that's kind of how I'm thinking of this last equation (most of these complex numbers are actually phasors, or vector-wannabes anyways).

**I need to find a way to express $x$ in terms of the known values.** Is this even possible without knowing $\theta_a$ or $d$?

I don't seem to be getting anywhere by breaking down the first two equations into Real and Imaginary parts - it seems to be making more unknown values, which just makes this messier. But if I commit to polar form I'm finding it hard to deal with the cosine. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: The dot product between complex numbers is defined : [What is the dot product of complex vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459814/what-is-the-dot-product-of-complex-vectors)

Comment: @Conan That entry refers to the dot product of complex vectors, a vector with complex coordinates, while here we're dealing with complex scalars. The dot product of a complex vector would have us multiply a complex scalar in one vector by the conjugate of the similarly-indexed complex scalar in the other vector - the way I'm "using" a dot product here is different.

Comment: Welcome! That's a great first question for someone new to this site.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = |a|e^{i\theta}$ (your $\theta_a$, but I'm dropping the subscript as a needless pain).
The first equation tells us that $$x = \frac{|a|e^{i\theta} - c}b$$ so if we can figure out $\theta$, then we can figure out $x$.

The second equation tells us that $$d = \frac{e|a|}be^{i\theta} +\left(f-\frac cb\right)$$

Now, $a\cdot d = \Re(\bar ad)$ ($\Re(z)$ denotes the real part of $z$). So the third equation tells us that
$$\Re\left[|a|e^{-i\theta}\left(\frac{e|a|}be^{i\theta} + f-\frac cb\right)\right] = P\\\Re\left(\frac{e|a|}b\right) + \Re\left[\left(f-\frac cb\right)e^{-i\theta}\right] = \frac P{|a|}$$

Letting $Q = \frac P{|a|} - \Re\left(\frac{e|a|}b\right)$ and $re^{i\phi} = f-\frac cb$, we get $$\Re\left(re^{i(\phi - \theta)}\right) = Q$$
$$\cos(\phi - \theta) = \frac Qr$$
As $Q, r, \phi$ are all defined by known quantities, you can solve the equation for $\theta$ (in general, there will be two non-equivalent solutions), and obtain $x$ using the equation for it above.