# Write all the unitary vectors of $\mathbb{C}^2$ in terms of real parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, orthonormal

> Write all the unitary vectors of $\mathbb{C}^2$ in terms of real parameters. After so, write all the orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$

I thought that for the first part, a vector $\vec{u}=(x_1,x_2)$ is unitary if $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1$, but I don't know how the book goes from here to directly put that the solutions are $$x_1=e^{i\alpha}\cos\theta$$ $$x_2=e^{i\beta}\sin \theta$$ Also clueless for the second part, I'm guessing I can do $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{x}=0$ for a generic vector $\vec{x}=(x_3,x_4)$

Comment: Think about scaling unit vectors in $\Bbb C$ by factors $a$ and $b$ so that $a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin what do you mean? By scaling aren't we increasing it's length and therefore can be bigger than 1? On any case I don't know what you mean

Comment: Hint : $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2 = 1$ means that the moduli lie on a circle.

Comment: If you scale by, say, $a=1/2$, then you certainly aren't increasing the length. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1,$$ you have a solution in terms of real numbers of the form $$x_1=\cos\theta\\x_2=\sin\theta,$$
where $\theta \in\mathbb R$.
But $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb C$, so you take the magnitudes ($|\sin\theta|$ and $|\cos\theta|$) and multiply by unit vectors in $\mathbb C$.
Therefore $$x_1=e^{i\alpha'}|\cos\theta|\\x_2=e^{i\beta'}|\sin\theta|$$
Here $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are any random real numbers. Note that $e^{i\pi}=-1$, so if $\cos\theta<0$, then $$|\cos\theta|=e^{i\pi}\cos\theta$$
This $\pi$ factor can be then absorbed into $\alpha=\alpha'+\pi$. A similar approach is valid for $\beta$

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments, I think I should clarify a couple of points:

1. Both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are complex numbers. Each complex number is equivalent to a pair of real numbers. So a vector in $\mathbb C^2$ has four components.
2. Let $x_1=r_1e^{i\alpha}$ and $x_2=r_2e^{i\beta}$. These are complex number written in the polar form. $e^{i\alpha}$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb C$. So you multiply a unit vector by the magnitude:$$x_1=|x_1|e^{i\alpha}$$
3. Then
   $$|\vec u|=(r_1\cos\alpha)^2+(r_1\sin\alpha)^2+(r_2\cos\beta)^2+(r_2\sin\beta)^2=r_1^2+r_2^2=1$$
   If you look at the last equation, both $r_1^2$ and $r_2^2$ are between $0$ and $1$. So if I choose $r_1=|\sin\theta|$ then I can write $r_2=|\cos\theta|$. With these, you get the form in the first question.

For the second part, this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459814/what-is-the-dot-product-of-complex-vectors) might provide some insight. It is a lot of calculation anyway.
$$\vec u\cdot\vec v=(\cos\theta e^{i\alpha},\sin\theta e^{i\beta})\cdot(\cos\gamma e^{i\mu},\sin\gamma e^{i\nu})=\cos\theta\cos\gamma e^{i(\alpha-\mu)}+\sin\theta\sin\gamma e^{i(\beta-\nu)}$$
It's easy to see that $\vec u\cdot\vec u=1$.
Now let's look for an orthogonal base. The number of vectors in such a base is $2$ (two complex numbers = 4 real numbers). Since $\vec u\cdot\vec v=0$, the six parameters and two constraints (real and imaginary parts are zero) yield 4 independent variables. There are several cases.

- $\cos\theta=0$. This yields $\sin\theta =1$ (the $-1$ case is just a change of phase in the exponent). That means $\sin\gamma=0$. In this case, the basis is $((0,e^{i\beta}),(e^{i\mu},0))$. You can choose any $\beta$ and $\nu$
- $\cos\gamma=0$. Similar case as before, with the same basis $((e^{i\alpha},0),(0,e^{i\nu}))$, in different order.
- $\cos\theta\cos\gamma\ne 0$. Then $$\frac{\sin\theta\sin\gamma}{\cos\theta\cos\gamma}e^{i(\beta-\nu-\alpha+\mu)}=-1$$. This means two things. One, $\tan\theta\tan\gamma=\pm1$, and two $\beta-\nu-\alpha+\mu=n\pi$. Odd $n$ values correspond to $\tan\theta\tan\gamma=1$ and even ones to $\tan\theta\tan\gamma=-1$.

Comment: sorry for answering late. But I still can't get over how the solution can't be just $x_1=\cos\theta$ and $x_2=\sin \theta$. It satisfies $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2=1$ and I can imagine all the vectors $\vec{u}=(x_1,x_2)$ plotted within a circle of radius 1, which is what I imagine the solution is looking for.

Comment: Unitary vectors of $\mathbb C^2$ means that you have 4 real numbers as components. When you choose $x_1=\cos\theta$ you only select $\alpha=0$. Remember that $x_1$ is a complex number.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't get through what you are saying, which 4 real numbers? I'm still confused to why can't just $x_1=\cos\theta, x_2=\sin\theta$ be the solution, I can imagine it plotting a **circle** with radius 1 in the complex plane, since all points of the circle can be written as $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, isn't it? Or is this wrong reasoning?

Comment: Any vector in $\mathbb C$ can be described by the real and imaginary part. Any vector in $\mathbb C^2$ has a real part and imaginary part for the first component, and a real and imaginary part for the second component. This is equivalent to four numbers. When you talk about the circle, you have only two components. What happened to the other two? Your $x_1$ and $x_2$ are complex numbers. Your condition for unitary vector is  $$(\Re x_1)^2+(\Im x_1)^2+(\Re x_2)^2+(\Im x_2)^2=1$$ In your approach, for some reason, you ignore the imaginary parts of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: okay I know what's wrong in my reasoning now, I thought the usual $\mathbb{C}^2$ was the normal one with the imaginary and real axis, but now I see that's $\mathbb{C}$. It now clicked, thanks!

Comment: Actually can you expand a little bit more on why we take the magnitudes $|\cos\theta |$ and multiply them with the unit vector of $\mathbb{C}$? I'm thinking about it as both $x_1$ and $x_2$ being each a vector each in $\mathbb{C}$, so to find the unitary vector we know that in general: $\hat{v}=\frac{\vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}$ so I would've **divided** by the magnitude instead of multiplying

Comment: @Acedium20 I've added more explanation, and solution to the second part

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1 =  x_{1r}+ix_{1i}$ and $x_2 = x_{2r}+ix_{2i}$
$$|x_{1r}|^2 + |x_{1i}|^2+|x_{2r}|^2+|x_{2i}|^2 = 1$$

Let without loss of generality, $$|x_{1r}|^2 + |x_{1i}|^2 = cos^2\alpha_1$$
Hence $$|x_{2r}|^2+|x_{2i}|^2 = sin^2\alpha_1$$

Hence, $$x_{1r} = cos\alpha_1 \times cos\alpha_2$$
$$x_{1i} = cos\alpha_1 \times sin\alpha_2$$
$$x_{2r} = sin\alpha_1 \times cos\alpha_3$$
$$x_{2i} = sin\alpha_1 \times sin\alpha_3$$

Hence any unit vector is of the the above form for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$.

Orthonormal basis is same as $2 \times 2 $ orthonormal matrix: $$A^{-1} = A^H$$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^H = = \begin{bmatrix}
a^* & c^* \\
b^* & d^* 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now setting $$A^{-1} = A^H$$, we have,

$$a = d^*, b = -c^*$$

Hence columns of the below matrix with $$|a|^2+|b|^2 = 1$$(general form of $a,b$ from first part of this answer) is your set of all orthonormal basis.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b^* & a^* 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}^2$ is isomorphic to tessarines via isomorphism:

$\left(x_1,x_2\right)\to \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+j\frac{x_2-x_1}{2} $

Representing $x_1$ and $x_2$ as complex numbers we get:

$\left(a_1+i b_1,a_2+i b_2\right)\to\frac{1}{2} j \left(a_2+i b_2-\left(a_1+i b_1\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(a_1+a_2+i b_1+i b_2\right)$

Expanding,

$\left(a_1+i b_1,a_2+i b_2\right)\to\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}+\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}i+\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}j+\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}  ij$

To get the modulus (magnitude), we have to take the squares of all components of this vector with positive sign except the coefficient of hyperbolic unity $j$:

$\left|\left(a_1+i b_1,a_2+i b_2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}\right)^2}$

So, the unit vectors are those for which $\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}\right)^2=1$