# (complex)Prove that there is no relationship $\prec$ in $\mathbb C$ such that:....

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, problem-solving

Prove that there is no relationship $\prec$ in $\mathbb C$ such that:

a) Given $z,w \in \mathbb C$, one and only one of the following conditions is valid:$z=w, z \prec w, w \prec z$.

b)If $z_1 \prec z_2$ and $z_3 \in \mathbb C$, then $z_1+z_3 \prec z_2+z_3$.

c)If $z_1 \prec z_2$ and $0 \prec z_3$, then $z_1z_3 \prec z_2z_3$.

a) $z = a + bi, w = c + di$

Case 1 $z=w \to  a=c, bi=di$ so $z \prec w$ or $w \prec z$ are false.

Case 2 $z \prec w \to  bi \lt di $ or $ bi = di$ and $a \lt c$

Case 3  $w \prec z \to  di \lt bi $ or $ bi = di$ and $c \lt a$
so if $z=w$ case 2 and 3 are impossible, if $z \prec w$  case 1 and 3 are impossible and if $w \prec z$  case 1 and 2 are impossible.

b) $z_1 = a + bi, z_2 = c + di, z_3 = e + fi$ if  $z_1 \prec z_2$ then $bi \lt di$ or $di = fi$ and $a \lt c$ so $z_1 = (a + bi) + z_3 = (e + fi) \prec z_2 = (c + di) + z_3 = (e + fi) \to (a + bi) + (e + fi) \prec  (c + di) + (e + fi) = (a+e) + i(b+f) \prec (c+e)+i(d+f)$ but $a+e \lt c+e$ and $b+f \lt d+f $ therefore $z_1 + z_3 \prec z_2 + z_3$.

c)  $z_1 = a + bi, z_2 = c + di, z_3 = e + fi$ if  $z_1 \prec z_2$ and $ 0 \prec z_3 $ then  $z_1 = (a + bi) * z_3 = (e + fi) \prec z_2 = (c + di) * z_3 = (e + fi) \to (a + bi) * (e + fi) \prec  (c + di) * (e + fi) = a*e + a*fi +bi*e + bi*fi \prec c*e + c*fi +di*e + di*fi =  (a*e - b*f)  + i(a*f +b*e) \prec (c*e - d*f)  + i(c*f +d*e)$ but $ a*e - b*f \lt c*e - d*f$ and $ a*f +b*e \lt c*f +d*e$ therefore $z_1z_3 \prec z_2z_3$.

Is my answer correct?

Grateful for the attention.

Comment: It's less work than you're making it out to be. Show $0\prec z^2$ for $z\ne0$, so $0\prec-1$, so $1\prec0$.

Comment: Do you mean "$=$" in the usual sense? As in, are you **given** the following: For any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, the set $\{z' \in \mathbb{C}; z'=z\}$, necessarily has exactly one element which is $z$ itself.

Comment: See the top [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers) under *Related* on the right-hand side.

Comment: I see a lot of statements, but I don't see a question here. What are you asking, Cel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total ordering on complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers)

Comment: a,b,c are meant to be take together as one statement (there is no < such that all 3 hold simultaneously), not 3 different statements.